# What's the SLD tree for this query?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics, prolog-cut

Let's consider the following Prolog program (from "The Art of Prolog"):

```
natural_number(0).
natural_number(s(X)) :- natural_number(X).

plus(X, 0, X) :- natural_number(X).
plus(X, s(Y), s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).
```

and the query:

```
?- plus(s(s(s(0))), s(0), Z).
```

Both SICStus and SWI produce the expected `Z = s(s(s(s(0))))` answer, but query the user for the next answer (a correct `no`/`false` answer). However, I cannot understand why there is an open branch in the SLD tree after the only goal is found. I tried debugging both under SICStus and under SWI, but I am not really able to interpret the result yet. I can only say that, as far as I could understand, both backtrack to `plus(s(s(s(0))), 0, _Z2)`. Can someone help me understanding this behavior?

Comment: You exchanged the first and second argument of `plus/3`compared to Program 3.3 of Art of Prolog. But leave it like that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to SLD trees, since Prolog 
systems do not build SLD trees in a look-ahead manner as 
you describe it.  But some optimizations found in certain Prolog 
systems essentially  have this effect and change the blind brute 
force head matching. Namely indexing and choice point elimination.

There is now a known limitation of SWI-Prolog. Although it does 
multi-argument indexing, it does not do <s>choice point elimination
for non-first argument indexes</s> cascaded indexing. Means
it only picks one argument, but then no further. There are some 
Prolog systems that do multi argument indexing and cascaded indexing. 
For example in [Jekejeke Prolog](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/15_stdy/06_bench/05_optimizations/02_index.html) we do not have No/false:

[image: Peano Cascade]

Bye

P.S.: The newest version of Jekejeke Prolog even does not 
literally cascade, since it detects that the first argument index
has no sensitivity. Therefore although it builds the index for
the first argument due to the actual call pattern, it skips the 
first argument index and does not use it, and solely uses the
second argument. Skipping gives a little speed. :-)

The skipping is seen via the [`dump/1`](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/10_dev/10_docu/02_reference/06_theories/01_inspect/04_index.html) command of the
development environment version:

```
?- dump(plus/3).
-------- plus/3 ---------
length=2
arg=0
  =length=2
arg=1
  0=length=1
  s=length=1
Yes
```

So it has not decended into `arg=0` and built an `arg=1`
index there, but instead built in parallel an `arg=0` and
an `arg=1` index. We might still call this heuristic cascading 
since individual queries lead to multiple indexes, but they 
have not really the shape of a cascade.

Comment: If I do not understand bad, you are saying that, if a term matches the functor and first parameter of a rule's head, SWI Prolog consider the rule as (potentially) matching and creates a choice point for it. Am I right?

Comment: @CookieMonster: <pre> permits to <s> and <b> in the text

Comment: @CookieMonster: So, if I did understand correctly, Prolog implementations do not always compute the exact set of clauses whose head matches a given predicate, just for the sake of efficiency. Indeed, by exchanging the declaration order of the plus rules, I can see that SWI creates a choice point at all levels. I think I got it. Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Many Prolog systems are not as smart as we expect them to be. This has several reasons, mostly because of a tradeoff choice of the implementer. What appears important to some might not be that important to others.

As a consequence these leftover choicepoints may accumulate in time and prevent to free auxiliary data. For example, when you want to read in a long list of text. A list that is that long that it does not fit into memory at once, but still can be processed efficiently with `library(pio)`.

If you expect exactly one answer, you might use `call_semidet/1` to make it determinate.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942551/772868) for its definition and a use case.

```
?- plus(s(s(s(0))), s(0), Z).
   Z = s(s(s(s(0))))
;  false.
?- call_semidet(plus(s(s(s(0))), s(0), Z)).
   Z = s(s(s(s(0)))).
```

But you can see it also from a more optimistic side: Modern toplevels (like the one in SWI) do show you when there are leftover choicepoints. So you can consider some countermeasures like `call_semidet/1`.

Here are some related answers:

- [implementing `last/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736042/772868)
- [how to insert green cuts into `append/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12710995/772868)

Answer (score 0):

To us, it's apparent that the two clauses for plus are 'disjunctive'. We can say that because we know that `0 \= s(Y)`. But (I think) such analysis in general is prohibitive, and Prolog then consider such branch still to be proved: here a trace showing that the call (7) is still 'open' for alternatives after the first solution has been found.

[image]

Comment: Problem with trace is that it adds choice points in most of the Prolog systems (SWI Prolog is an exception here, means also you don't see all ports for deterministic executions), so the method is not in general reliable to explain why something is not deterministic.

Comment: @CookieMonster: is it in this peculiar case? There is only one pending choice point both in the query and in trace, so I would assume it is the case.

Comment: Chac is right. I only wanted to point out that in some Prolog systems the trace mode might change the choice point elimination behaviour. This is because trace is sometimes implemented under the hood as replace each goal G, by (port(call); port(fail), fail), G, (port(exit); port(redo), fail), which adds choice points and changes the propagation of determinism.

Comment: @Cookie Monster: If correctly done, I would expect no change in behaviour for the transformation you show. Otherwise, such a debug tool would be of very little use.

Comment: Yes, debug tools which leave choice points slow down the execution, or eat up memory space. This is seen in many early Prolog systems.