# Prolog disjunction

Tags: prolog

Consider this Prolog predicate:

```
silly:-
    1 = 1.
silly:-
    1 = 2.
```

When querying, the output answer has two states: true and then false. Is there anyway to ask Prolog to terminate as soon as it hits a true statement in a disjunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a cut

```
silly:-
    1 = 1, !.
silly:-
    1 = 2.
```

or use if/then/else, but then the 'program' take a very different shape, being the alternative branches merged into a single clause. Also note that, as stated in documentation

> Unlike !/0, the choice point of the predicate as a whole (due to multiple clauses) is not destroyed.

```
silly:-
    ( 1 = 1 -> true ; false ).
```

Comment: Ahh.. your solution is elegant! Gotta do some more reading about cuts. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Generally speaking, cuts are mostly used for implementing negation by failure. This is an interesting stackoverflow 'debate' on the appropriate use of Prolog cuts you might want to have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541164/knowing-when-to-use-cut-in-prolog

Answer (score 6):

The question is "*Is there anyway to ask Prolog to terminate as soon as it hits a true statement in a disjunction*"?

The answer is "*Use `once/1` when querying for the answer*".

For example:

```
     ?- [user] .
     silly:-
     1=1 .
     silly:-
     1=2 .
     silly:-
     2=2 .
     end_of_file .

     ?- %% query WITHOUT once {results in 2 answers} : %%
     silly .
     true ;
     true.

     ?- %% query WITH once {results in 1 answer} : %%
     once(silly) .
     true.
```

The use of cut `!` does not meet the semantic requirements of the question as stated.

Using cut would be appropriate if the question had been more like "Is there anyway to <s>ask</s> **tell** Prolog to terminate as soon as it hits <s>a true statement</s>** a statement specially indicated* in a disjunction" ?

Comment: A light bulb went off for me when I realised this is equivalent to `once(1=1;1=2;2=2)`. In other words, separate rules are just disjunction clauses, and `once` stops once it reaches one that succeeds. So it's also equivalent to defining `silly :- 1=1; 1=2; 2=2.` and calling `once(silly)`. Which as the other answer covers, is equivalent to `silly :- (1=1,!);(1=2,!);2=2.`. Handy when the leaves of knowledge form branches of a tree!