# I want to count the occurrences of an element in a list

Tags: list, count, prolog, clpfd, prolog-dif

I want to count the occurrences of an element in a list, and if there is one then the predicate unique would be true, else false. However, if the element occurs more than once, Prolog finds it true. I don't know what to do...

```
count([], X, 0).
count([X|T], X, Y) :- count(T, X, Z), Y is 1+Z, write(Z).
count([_|T], X, Z) :- count(T, X, Z).

unique(St, [Y|RestList]) :- count([Y|RestList], St, N), N =:= 1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution works as far as the first argument is a ground list. In some other cases, it is incorrect:

```
?- count([E], a, 0).
   false.
```

Here we ask

> How must the element `E` of a list of length 1 look like such that the list contains 0 occurences of `a`?

And in fact there are answers to this, like `E = b` or `E = c`:

```
?- count([b],a,0).
   true.
?- count([c],a,0).
   true.
```

For this reason Prolog's answer was *incomplete*. It should have said, yes. But how?

```
count([], _, 0).
count([E|Es], F, N0) :-
   count(Es, F, N1),
   if_(E = F, D = 1, D = 0),
   N0 is N1+D.
```

This uses [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868) and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532461/772868).

```
?- length(Xs, I), count_dif(Xs, a, N).
   Xs = [], I = N, N = 0
;  Xs = [a], I = N, N = 1
;  Xs = [_A], I = 1, N = 0, dif(_A, a)
;  Xs = [a, a], I = N, N = 2
;  Xs = [_A, a], I = 2, N = 1, dif(_A, a)
;  Xs = [a, _A], I = 2, N = 1, dif(_A, a)
;  Xs = [_A, _B], I = 2, N = 0, dif(_A, a), dif(_B, a)
; ... .
```

To further improve this, we might use `library(clpfd)` as it is available in SICStus, YAP, and SWI.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

count([], _, 0).
count([E|Es], F, N0) :-
   N0 #>= 0,
   if_(E = F, D = 1, D = 0),
   N0 #= N1+D,
   count(Es, F, N1).
```

Now even the following terminates:

```
?- count([a,a|_], a, 1).
   false.
?- N #< 2, count([a,a|_], a, N).
   false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your own clauses, I just optimize a little the program:

- replace singleton variables by anonymous variable
- Add a cut on the second clause of the count predicate
- Delete second condition of the unique clause.

This is the program now:

```
count([],_,0).

count([X|T],X,Y):- !, count(T,X,Z), Y is 1+Z.

count([_|T],X,Z):- count(T,X,Z).

unique(St,L):- count(L,St,1).
```

consult:

```
?- count([2,3,4,3], 3,N).
N = 2.

?- unique(3, [2,3,4,5]).
true.
```

Comment: Wow it works perfectly you are the best, thanks a lot i ve been working on this exercice many many hours, thanks so much!!!