# Prolog - Check number of occurences doesn't work as expected

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

In Prolog:
I have the following function that counts the occurences of a certain element in a list:

```
%count(L:list,E:int,N:int) (i,i,o)
count([],_,0).
count([H|T],E,C):-H == E,count(T,E,C1),C is C1+1.
count([_|T],E,C):-count(T,E,C).
```

I tested it and it works well. But here comes the problem, I have another function that has to check if "1" occurs less than 2 times in a list.

```
check(L):-count(L,1,C),C<2.
```

Whenever I try to check the list `[1,1,1,1]` for example, the result I get is "true", which is wrong, and I have no idea why. I tried to make some changes, but the function just won't work.

Comment: Look at the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971616/4609915 to the *very* related question here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/28951199/4609915 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `count([1,1,1,1],1,1)` is also true! In your last `count` it can also be matched when H does equal E. To illustrate this, use `;` to make prolog look for more answers to `count([1,1,1,1],1,R)`. You'll see what happens.

```
count([],_,0).
count([E|T],E,C):-
    count(T,E,C1),
    C is C1+1.
count([H|T],E,C):-
    H \= E,
    count(T,E,C).

check(L) :- 
    count(L,1,C),
    C < 2.
```

```
?- check([1,1,1,1,1]).
false
?- check([1]).
true
```

Comment: beware the semantic is different, maybe unintentionally, OP' original test cannot be replaced by unification

Comment: Thank you so much, I just figured out I forgot to insert "the cut" in the second clause, but due to your answer I saw what went wrong, and both versions work as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Improve your testing habits!**

When testing Prolog code don't only look at the first answer to some query and conclude "*it works*".

Non-determinism **is** central to Prolog.

Quite often, some code *appears* to be working correctly at first sight (when looking at the first answer) but exhibits problems (mainly wrong answers and/or non-termination) upon backtracking.

---

Coming back to your original question... If you want / need to preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity), consider using the following minimal variation of the code [@Ruben presented in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33804991/4609915):

```
count([],_,0).
count([E|T],E,C) :-
   count(T,E,C1),
   C is C1+1.
count([H|T],E,C) :- 
   dif(H,E),
   count(T,E,C).
```

`dif/2` expresses syntactic term inequality in a logical sound way. For info on it look at [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)!

Answer (score 0):

second and third clauses heads match both the same sequence. As a minimal correction, I would commit the test

```
count([],_,0).
count([H|T],E,C):-H == E,!,count(T,E,C1),C is C1+1.
count([_|T],E,C):-count(T,E,C).
```