# Counting occurrences in list

Tags: list, count, prolog, clpfd, prolog-dif

I'm trying to create a rule that counts the number of occurrences of a certain element in a given list, what I've tried so far does not seem to work the way I expect:

The first *argument* here should be the list, the second one the element we are looking for, and the last one the number of occurrences:

```
%empty list should always return 0 occurences
count([],E,0) :- true.

%if our head is what we are looking for, count
count([E|T],E,N) :- count(T,E,N-1).

%otherwise, do not count
count([H|T],E,N) :- H \== E, count(T,E,N).
```

Here `H` is the *head* and `T` the *tail* of the given list.

The base case e.g. `count([],1,N).` returns `N = 0` as expected, but as soon as the list is non empty, we always get `false.`:

```
?- count([1],1,N).
false.
?- count([1,2,1,3],1,N).
false.
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

#### Update:

It seems to work when replacing the second line with

```
count([E|T],E,N+1) :- count(T,E,N).
```

But I just cannot figure out why this is not equivalent to my first idea.

Then we get

```
?- count([1,2,1,3],1,N).
N = 0+1+1
```

which is correct.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951199/i-want-to-count-the-occurences-of-an-element-in-a-list?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. I did actually find that answer, but I still do not see the reasons why mine does *not* work.

Comment: don't forget: `count(L,E,C) :- aggregate(count,member(E,L),C).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `N+1` (or `N-1`) isn't evaluated, as can be seen by your second (working) example.

```
% empty list has 0 occurrences
count([], _, 0).

% if our head is what we are looking for, count
count([E|T], E, N) :-
    N_1 is N - 1,         % this is the important one
    count(T, E, N_1).

% otherwise, do not count
count([H|T], E, N) :-
    H \== E,
    count(T, E, N).
```

`is` actually *evaluates* the equation, instead of *unifying* the `N` in your next call with `N-1`. That's why in your second example, you end up with `N=0+1+1` instead of `N=2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have trouble understanding why the *N+1* works while the *N-1* example does not, both seem to express the very same thing to me, do they?

Comment: Because in the second example, N doesn't become unified until you hit the 0, after which all the +1's are "glued on" when traversing the tree back up. In the first example, the -1's are already there, so your next N is "N-1", "N-1-1" and so on, which never unifies with a 0. I'll edit this into my answer later.

Answer (score 4):

**Evaluation versus Unification**

In Prolog `=/2` is a *unification* operator. It does not evaluate a term as an expression even if the term might represent something numerically evaluable. Similarly, when you use `count([E|T], E, N+1)`, Prolog *does not* evaluate the term `N+1`. To Prolog, that's just another term, which internally is represented as `+(N, 1)`.

For a term to be interpreted and evaluated as a numeric expression, you need to use specific Prolog operators that will do that. As @SQB points out, one of these is `is/2`:

```
N = 1, N1 is N + 1.
```

This will result in `N1 = 2`. However this:

```
N = 1, N1 = N + 1.
```

Will result in: `N1 = 1 + 1` (or equivalently, `N1 = +(1, 1)`).

There are also numeric comparison operators in Prolog that will also compute expressions. These are `=:=/2`, `>/2`, `>=/2`, `</2` and `=</2`. So you will see the following:

```
1 + 2 =:= 3.
```

Will yield "true" since `=:=/2` is specifically for comparing equality of evaluable numeric expressions. However:

```
1 + 2 = 3.
```

Will yield "false" because the term `+(1,2)` does not match (or more accurately, cannot be unified with) the term `3`.

**Argh! Arguments not sufficiently instantiated!**

I've seen quite a few posts on SO regarding an error that their arguments are "not sufficiently instantiated". Many of these are in the use of `is/2`. As described above, `is/2` will evaluate the expression in the 2nd argument and then unify that result with the first argument. The 2nd argument *must be fully evaluable* (all variables involved in the expression must be instantiated with a numeric value) or you'll get an error. Likewise, when using the expression comparisons, all of the variables in both arguments must be fully instantiated. Thus, if `X` is a variable that is unbound, the following will yield an "arguments not sufficiently instantiated" error:

```
9 is X * 3.       % Will NOT yield X = 3, but will give an error
Y + 2 =:= X * 2.  % Error if either X or Y are not instantiated
Y = 1, X = 2, Y + 2 =:= X * 2.  % Yields "false" (fails) since 3 is not equal to 4
Y = 1, X = 2, Y + 2 < X * 2.    % Yields "true" (succeeds) since 3 is less than 4
Y = 1, X = 2, X + 1 = Y + 2.    % Yields "false" since +(2,1) doesn't unify with +(1,2)
```

When performing constraint logic on expressions, the tool to use is the CLP(FD) library. Thus:

```
X * 3 #= 6.
```

Will yield, `X = 2`.