# Prolog count numbers of elements Error

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I'm learning prolog, and I want to count a specific element occurence in a list.

So here is the code -

```
count(_, [], _) := !.

count(El, [El|T], N) :-
    N1 is N + 1,
    count(El, T, N1).

count(El, [_|T], N) :-
    count(El, T, N).

check(List1, List2) :-
    count(3, List1, M),
    count(2, List2, N),
    M is N.
```

so basically I would like to pass to console check([3,4,3], [2,3,4,5,2]), and it should return true, because occurences of 3 in list1 is the same as occurences of 2 in list2. But instead it throws me -

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. 
Exception: (10) _G1383 is _L155+1 ? creep
Exception: (9) count(3, [3, 4, 2], _G1385) ? creep
Exception: (8) count(3, [2, 3, 4, 2], _G1385) ? creep
Exception: (7) check([2, 3, 4, 2], [2, 3, 4]) ? creep
```

What is the cause of this, and how can I solve it? I checked all around forum, and everywhere it's written that this should work. Is this some kind of version related stuff, or really I'm missing here something?

EDIT: Using **SWI-Prolog**.

EDIT2:

Got it working, thank you!

Code:

```
count(_, [], 0) :- !.

count(El, [El|T], N) :-
    count(El, T, N1),
    N #= N1 + 1.

count(El, [Y|T], N) :-
    El \= Y,
    count(El, T, N).

check(List1, List2) :-
    count(3, List1, M),
    count(2, List2, N),
    M #= N.
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971616/772868) for a pure and efficient solution.

Comment: You need at least `dif(E1, Y),` in place of `E1 \= Y,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using predicates that are called **moded** because they can only be used in very specific situations. In particular, `(is)/2` cannot be used as a relation as you need it here.

One way to solve this is to use **more general predicates** instead. For example, when reasoning over *integers*, consider using your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints**, which work in all directions.

For example, with GNU Prolog, you can make the error go away if you simply *replace* `(is)/2` by `(#=)/2`:

```
count(_, [], _).

count(El, [El|T], N) :-
    N1 #= N + 1,
    count(El, T, N1).

count(El, [_|T], N) :-
    count(El, T, N).

check(List1, List2) :-
    count(3, List1, M),
    count(2, List2, N),
    M #= N.
```

Now we get:

```
?- count(3, [3, 4, 2], C).
C+1#=_1204 ;
true ;
false.
```

(or, depending on your Prolog system, an equivalent answer).

*Why*? Obviously, the program is a bit flawed.

I leave finding the mistake as an exercise. Hint: `M #= N` looks suspicious: This is true **iff** `M` is *equal to* `N`...

Comment: I guess #= in SWI-prolog counts as comments, need to check it. Edited answer to update, which prolog I'm using.

Comment: In SICStus Prolog, YAP and SWI, you need to add `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` at the beginning to use declarative integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you got it working now, by using declarative arithmetic!

I have a few minor additional comments about the solution you obtained, i.e.:

```
count(_, [], 0) :- !.

count(El, [El|T], N) :-
    count(El, T, N1),
    N #= N1 + 1.

count(El, [Y|T], N) :-
    El \= Y,
    count(El, T, N).

check(List1, List2) :-
    count(3, List1, M),
    count(2, List2, N),
    M #= N.
```

First, note that `check/2` is nowhere used in the code, so I omit its definition in the following.

## Most general query

When I review Prolog code I know nothing about, I always try the **most general query** first, where all arguments are variables. Ideally, the answers show me what solutions look like **in general**.

For example, in your case:

```
?- count(E, Ls, C).
Ls = [],
C = 0.
```

This—erroneously—suggests that there is only a **single** solution of your predicate! This is obviously not intended.

Therefore, as a first step, I recommend you **remove the `!/0`** and change this code to:

```
count(_, [], 0).

count(El, [El|T], N) :-
    count(El, T, N1),
    N #= N1 + 1.

count(El, [Y|T], N) :-
    El \= Y,
    count(El, T, N).
```

With this change applied, we get:

```
?- count(E, Ls, C).
Ls = [],
C = 0 ;
Ls = [E],
C = 1 ;
Ls = [E, E],
C = 2 ;
Ls = [E, E, E],
C = 3 .
```

This looks much better: We now get several **valid answers**.

## Termination

**How many** answers might this predicate yield? In particular, are there only *finitely* many answers? If so, we would expect the following query to **terminate**:

```
?- count(E, Ls, C), false.
```

You can try it, and see that it in fact *doesn't* terminate (at least not very soon). That's a *good sign*, because from a *correct* implementation of `count/3`, we **expect nontermination** in the most general case!

## Completeness

Ideally, we would like the predicate to be **complete**: It should not *omit* valid answers.

For example:

```
?- count(E, [X,Y,Z], C).
E = X, X = Y, Y = Z,
C = 3 ;
false.
```

Are these really *all solutions*? I don't think so! Certainly there are lists of length 3 that are different from `[E,E,E]`.

And, in fact, your program also "knows" about them in a sense:

```
?- count(E, [1,2,3], C).
E = C, C = 1 ;
false.
```

But again, these are certainly not *all cases*! Where are the answers in which `E` is **different** from 1?

You are facing these issues because you are using the **non-monotonic** `(\=)/2` predicate. This has a few very hard to understand properties, especially if you are currently only beginning to learn Prolog. For example:

```
?- X \= Y, X-Y = a-b.
false.

?- X-Y = a-b, X \= Y.
X = a,
Y = b.
```

I recommend to **use `dif/2`** instead to denote that two terms are **different**, obtaining the following version:

```
count(_, [], 0).

count(El, [El|T], N) :-
    count(El, T, N1),
    N #= N1 + 1.

count(El, [Y|T], N) :-
    dif(El, Y),
    count(El, T, N).
```

Wit this version, we get:

```
?- count(E, [X,Y,Z], C).
E = X, X = Y, Y = Z,
C = 3 ;
E = X, X = Y,
C = 2,
dif(Y, Z) ;
E = X, X = Z,
C = 2,
dif(Z, Y) ;
etc.
```

And, in particular:

```
?- count(E, [1,2,3], C).
E = C, C = 1 ;
E = 2,
C = 1 ;
E = 3,
C = 1 ;
C = 0,
dif(E, 3),
dif(E, 2),
dif(E, 1).
```

This covers **all cases** that can arise!

## Fair enumeration

Since the predicate is **pure** and **monotonic**, we can use it to *fairly enumerate* answers by **iterative deepening**.

For example:

```
?- length(Ls, _), count(E, Ls, C).
Ls = [],
C = 0 ;
Ls = [E],
C = 1 ;
Ls = [_G588],
C = 0,
dif(E, _G588) ;
Ls = [E, E],
C = 2 ;
Ls = [E, _G597],
C = 1,
dif(E, _G597) .
C = 2 ;
etc.
```

That's pretty nice, and shows that we can use this as a true **relation**, not only for *counting*, but also for **generating**.

Hence, you may consider a predicate **name** that more appropriately describes what this predicate means **in general**. I leave this as an exercise.

## Tail recursive version

Note that since you are using **pure** predicates, you can freely *reorder* your goals, and make your predicate **tail recursive**, yielding:

```
count(_, [], 0).
count(El, [El|T], N) :-
    N #= N1 + 1,
    count(El, T, N1).
count(El, [Y|T], N) :-
    dif(El, Y),
    count(El, T, N).
```

## Determinism

We currently still have for example:

```
?- count(a, [a,a,a], Cs).
Cs = 3 ;
false.
```

Using `if_/3`, you can improve **determinism** of this predicate:

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

count(_, [], 0).
count(E, [L|Ls], N) :-
        if_(E=L, N #= N1 + 1, N #= N1),
        count(E, Ls, N1).
```

This makes your predicate at least **amenable** to indexing. Whether you improve determinism in such cases depends on your Prolog system's indexing mechanism.