# What is "!" in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-cut

Could somebody explain me what does "!" do in Prolog ? I don't understand it.
Here I have a code that counts how many sublists of a heterogeneous list have mountain aspect.

```
nrSubliste([], 0).
nrSubliste([H|T], R):-
    is_list(H),
    munteMain(H),!,
    nrSubliste(T, R1),
    R is R1 + 1.
nrSubliste([_|T], R):-
    nrSubliste(T, R).
```

`munteMain` verifies if a linear list has a mountain aspect.

Comment: Also check out the [canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14556019/1613573) on when to use `!/0` in Prolog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclamation point `!` denotes [*Cut*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(logic_programming)) in Prolog, a special goal that always succeeds, and blocks *backtracking* for all branches above it that may have alternatives.

In your case it means that once a solution to `munteMain/1` has been found, the program will never backtrack and look for an alternative solution. Specifically, Prolog will never consider the third clause of your `nrSubliste/2` rule, i.e. the one ignoring list head with `_`, if `H` in the second clause is such that `munteMain(H)` succeeds.

Note that using `!` makes your code is somewhat harder to read and maintain, because the logic in the third clause depends on the logic of the second clause. You can rewrite your program without a cut using the *not provable* [operator `\+`](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/negation.html):

```
nrSubliste([H|T], R):-
    is_list(H),
    munteMain(H),
    nrSubliste(T, R1),
    R is R1 + 1.

nrSubliste([H|T], R):-
    is_list(H),
    \+ munteMain(H),
    nrSubliste(T, R).
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understood it and thank you a lot for the alternative of using operator \+.