# Prolog: Checking if something is the last item in the list?

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

I am new to prolog and am basically trying to write a clause that would evaluate as true if a given item is the last item in a given list. Here is what I have:

```
last(X,[Y|X]).
last(X,[Y|Z]) :- last(X,Z).
```

I thought this would do the trick, but when I ask prolog:

```
?- last(c,[a,b,c]).
```

Prolog returns false. I tried the following query to see what Prolog thinks should fit my definition of last:

```
?- last(c,X).
X = [_G530|c] ;
X = [_G530, _G533|c] ;
X = [_G530, _G533, _G536|c]
```

So, what I am not sure about is why the "|" symbol is still in the list?

Update: last([c],[a,b,c]) produces the desired behavior. However, I'm not sure why my 1st argument has to be a list?

Answer (score 11):

You might want this:

```
 last(X,[X]).
 last(X,[_|Z]) :- last(X,Z).
```

The `|` denotes a 'tail' or 'the rest of the list.'

With `?- last(c,X).` Prolog produces lists (according to your first definition) that have c as the last item.

When you query `?- last(c,[a,b,c]).`, it returns false because you haven't defined a case for a list of only one item `[X]` or `[X|[]]`. So it fails when list is shorter than two items.

However, `last([c],[a,b,c])` succeeds because you get `[b|_29]` or whatever denoting that the tail part might be any list. So it '_29' can be '[c]', satisfying the first definition like `last([c],[b|[c]]).` Remember that a nonempty list in Prolog is actually a pair of the first list item (head) and a list of the rest (tail). Usually written as [head|tail].

Comment: best to avoid singletons: `last(X,[_|Z]) :- last(X,Z).`

Comment: True. Especially when warnings might confuse a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

Why not view things from a grammatical viewpoint. So what is the last element in a list?

```
last(X, Xs) :-
   phrase( ( ..., [X] ), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... . % any sequence
```

Comment: I get `2 ?- last(X, [1,2,3]). <br/>
X = 3 ; <br/>
false.`. Is this to be expected?

Comment: hmm. I expected it should be deterministic, but now that I try, I can't make it so without using a cut - `last(X,[_|B]):- B=[_|_],!, last(X,B).`, `last(X,[X]):- !.`. this is unexpected.

Comment: @WillNess: Let's not confuse logical determinism with a concrete performance feature. With ! as you indicate, you are sacrificing logical completeness for "performance". `last(X,[X|Xs])` should succeed for infinitely many answers.

Comment: @WillNess: Clever usage of ! might be possible, but it is a nightmare, and definitely not worth the effort. After all: There is a single choice point that is superfluous. It would be something else if there would be as many choicepoints as elements in the list. That would be serious, indeed. The Prolog convention to put the recursive rule last avoids that sometimes.

Comment: A perfect implementation is in: It does not use *any* cuts and avoids the superflous choice point.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734986/implementing-last-in-prolog

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use append?

```
last(X,Y) :-
    append(_,[X],Y).
```

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3

Answer (score 2):

Because the tail of a list is a list itself.

A list in Prolog can be seen as `[H | T]`, where `H` is the first element (the head), and `T` (the tail) is *a list* of all other elements.

Your list `[a, b, c]` is actually `[a | [b | [c | [] ] ] ]` when you decompose it (the last tail is always an empty list):

```
List: [a, b, c]   Head: a   Tail: [b, c]
List: [b, c]      Head: b   Tail: [c]
List: [c]         Head: c   Tail: []
```

So when you get to the point where you're asking if `last(c, [b, c])`, that decomposes to `last(c, [b|[c]])`, which is why the first clause can't be instantiated, because `X` can't be both `c` and `[c]`. That is why it *did* work when you asked `last([c],[a,b,c])`.

The [version proposed by alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21694728/2936460) works, because it takes this into account:

```
% A list ends with an element if contains exactly that element.
last(X,[X]).

% A list ends with an element if its tail ends with that element.
% (Since we don't care about the head, we use an underscore).
last(X,[_|T]) :- last(X,T).
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pic of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78uCc.png)

(a) using concatenation,

```
conc(_,[Item],List)
```

(b) Using without concatenation,

```
Last([Item],[Item]) :- Last(Item,[H|T]) , Last(Item,T)
```